# How to delete node using depth first traversal

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
       a              
      /|\            
     b f  c           
   /  /   
  d  x
 /\
e  h
```

I have this kind of tree structure in my application. I want to traverse this tree depth first and delete the nodes depth first. Node can have multiple childs.

I tried to do but it is deleting not in depth first order like e,h,d,b,x,f,c,a. I mean it should delete childs nodes then parent node.

```
function deleteNode(node) {
    let childs = node.getChildrens();
    if(childs === undefined || childs === null) {
        remove(node);
    } else
        for(int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            // if childs then 
            deleteNode(childs[i])
        }
    }   
    remove(node);
}
```

Comment: delete is a reserved word. change you function name

Comment: [tag:java] or [tag:javascript]? Chose one of the two. Also, why do you need to delete individual nodes? Why not just delete the root note?

Comment: Anywhere, it is just snippet of code. I will implement this in multiple language.

Comment: @AmitWagner it is calling correct delete which I am trying

Comment: It's still a good idea to change the function name.

Comment: I did, but no change. Is my logic is correct as per the depth first ?

Comment: Your logic SEEMS correct. Can you provide your complete implementation where this doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no way of knowing what is going wrong with your setup, but perhaps you could try moving the outer `remove(node)` into your `else` handler:

```js
function deleteNode(node) {
    let childs = node.getChildrens();
    if(childs === undefined || childs === null) {
        remove(node);
    } else
        for(int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            // if childs then 
            deleteNode(childs[i])
        }
        remove(node);
    }
}
```

Or better yet, simplify the logic further:

```js
function deleteNode(node) {
    // recurse through all the children first
    let childs = node.getChildrens();
    for(int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        deleteNode(childs[i])
    }

    // then delete itself
    remove(node);
}
```

As it currently is, your `remove(node)` call is being executed twice on children nodes, which may be the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, when you have deleted a child node, the length of  childnode array decreases.
I will suggest change your for loop ,from current

```
for(int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            // if childs then 
            deleteNode(childs[i])
        }
```

to

```
while( node.getChildrens().length>0) {
            // if childs then 
            deleteNode(childs[0])
        }
```